# Список, который указан, как атрибут экземпляра класса остается общим для всех остальных экземпляров данного класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Создаю класс, атрибутом которого является список с уникальными значениями для каждого экземпляра.

```
class FooClass:
    def __init__(self, list_attr=[]):
        # Список, который должен быть уникальным для каждого нового экземпляра класса FooClass
        self.list_attr = list_attr

    def add_to_list_attr(self, new_item):
        """метод, для добавления объектов в список self.list_attr, 
           который предполагался как уникальный для каждого экземпляра 
           класса FooClass"""
        self.list_attr.append(new_item)
```

Если я правильно понимаю смысл ключевого слова `self` в Питоне, то оно должно сделать список `self.list_attr` уникальным для каждого нового создаваемого объекта `FooClass`. Поэтому в методе `add_to_list_attr(self, new_item)` первым аргументом также указано `self`.

Однако на выходе я получаю это:

```
>>> foo1 = FooClass()

>>> foo1.list_attr
[]

>>> foo1.add_to_list_attr(1)

>>> foo1.list_attr
[1]

>>> foo2 = FooClass()

>>> foo2.list_attr
[1]

>>> foo2.add_to_list_attr(2)

>>> foo2.list_attr
[1, 2]

>>> foo1.list_attr
[1, 2]
```

То есть  `self.list_attr` ведет себя, словно это статичный атрибут для класса в целом, а не атрибут экземпляра класса. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем причина и как добиться желаемого поведения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это известная фича, если вкратце, то нужно делать так:

```
def __init__(self, list_attr=None):
    # Список, который должен быть уникальным для каждого нового экземпляра класса FooClass
    if list_attr is None:
        list_attr = []
    self.list_attr = list_attr
```

Смысл примерно в том, что если вы задаёте дефолтный параметр функции, то он инициализируется только один раз. При создании новых экземпляров класса новой инициализации уже не происходит. Поэтому в дефолтных параметрах нужно использовать не пустой список, а `None`, а уже внутри функции проверять на `None` и создавать новый список. Это просто нужно знать.

И проявляется это не только в методах класса, а в любых функциях:

```
def myfunc(mylist = []):
    mylist.append(1)
    return mylist

myfunc()
print(myfunc())
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 1]
```

Comment: Согласен, но удобнее было бы инициализировать элемент сразу при создании объекта, вот так: foo1 = FooClass([]).

Comment: @bolt_py А любой из вариантов кода никак не мешает вам так делать, вы всегда можете передать параметр в явном виде и он будет использован вместо дефолтного. Но особенности поведения дефолтных параметров у Питона надо знать на всякий случай.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ) Я почти голову сломал, так как думал, что это какая-то особенность логики инициализации объектов, а в сторону переданного по дефолту аргумента даже не подумал копнуть)