# Проблемы с наследованием нескольких классов от одного родительского

Tags: python, классы, наследование

В данный момент занимаюсь написанием модуля, где столкнулся с проблемой, которую хорошо иллюстрирует следующий пример.

```
class FatherClass:

    def __init__(self, name:str, childs:list = []):
        self._childs = childs

    def add_child(self, child):
        self._childs.append(child)

    def print_info(self):
        print(self._childs)

class Subclass1(FatherClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('s1')

class Subclass2(FatherClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('s2')

s1 = Subclass1()
s2 = Subclass2()

s1.add_child('123')
s2.add_child(s1)
s2.add_child('456')

s1.print_info()
```

Результатом выполнения этого кода будет

```
['123', <__main__.Subclass1 object at 0x0000023774EF1F70>, '456']
```

То есть, насколько я понял, объекты s1 и s2 имеют аттрибут _childs, ссылающийся на один и тот же участок памяти. Почему такое может происходить, ведь при инициализации сабклассов по-идее должен создаваться отдельный новый список для каждого нового объекта, и как получить требуемое поведение при наследовании (чтоб для каждого объекта подкласса создавались новые независящие друг от друга аттрибуты)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Список, который указан, как атрибут экземпляра класса остается общим для всех остальных экземпляров данного класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219264)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем отличие двух функций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534663/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9)